# Anagrams Question

Tags: combinatorics

How many anagrams of the word mississippi are there that have at least two consecutive i’s?
My approach was: Finding the total amount of anagrams (11! / 4! 4! 2!).
And then to calculate the amount of options without 2 consecutive i's.
In the end, to find the difference between them.
However, the result felt me to big intuitively.
Do I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you have a typo.  You mean ${11!\over 4!4!2!}$  Is this what's making your answer too big?

Comment: You are correct. it's 4!4!2!. Editing

Answer (score 7):

There is a way to do this, actually.

First, order the letters MSSSSPP. This can be done in $\displaystyle \frac{7!}{4!2!}=105$ ways.

Now, you have $8$ spaces between those letters to possibly insert I's (ends included).

Now, choose $4$ of those $8$ spaces to insert an $I$.

This gives a total of $105\cdot 70=7350$ ways.

Now, we are looking for the complement, so our answer is $\displaystyle \frac{11!}{4!4!2!}-7350=34650-7350=27300$ ways.

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation!